# X11 not starting correctly

Tags: linux, centos, xorg, i3-window-manager

I'm using the i3 window manager on Centos 6.5, with no GDM. I can boot fine, log in via the console, all works fine.

When I do `startx` to load my `.xinitrc` file and start i3, it appears to start X, but not display the desktop at all. I get a mouse pointer I can move, and the system is starting programs as I can use shortcuts to open a terminal or firefox and the pointer changes, however, I just have a blank screen and can't see anything!

**Addendum**: the only errors/warnings in the Xorg log file appear to be from input devices not being detected properly, such as headphone sockets etc. This is not an issue. The only possible source of error is a warning:

```
"(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa"
```

...but then it builds the default screen section for X11 and carries on fine. I'm stumped!

**Addendum 2**: If I kill my borked X session, and then do `sudo init 5`, I get the GDM login window and all displays correctly. Could there be a missing service/module that isn't loaded when I do `startx`?

Comment: Could you please add your .xinitrc?